# How can I ignore a directory when doing a Git bisect?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-bisect

I have a production build directory which often conflicts when merging branches. That's a separate issue. I need to find a problem in the commit history using Git bisect, but I get the following error:

> Bisecting: a merge base must be tested
>
> error: Untracked working tree file 'problem_directory/filename.ext' would be overwritten by merge.

Can I ignore `problem_directory` during the bisect process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build directories should not be checked in for exactly the reason you're encountering.

Consider adding it to `.gitignore` and using a tool like [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to remove it from history. Then it will not be a problem for your bisects.

Alternatively, clean up the build directory when your testing is done. If you're using `git bisect run`, put `make clean` or the equivalent in your build system at the end of the script.